# parsing an xml file

Tags: python, xml

so I have an xml file and a python code. With the elementree lib, I have to read the paths contained in  , concatenate all of those values and put them in a f_path. 
So far, I am able to the all path values but I can't concatenate them in my f_path:
Here's my python code et the xml file:
Thanks in advance

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.5
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('path.xml') 
rootElements = tree.getroot() 

    for racine in rootElements.findall('racine'):
    path = racine.find('path').text 
    print path
    if path != None: 
    f_path = path + "/"
print f_path
```

```
<racine name="RACINE1"> 
<path>MODELS</path> in here the path is : MODELS/USM/src
</racine> 

<racine name="RACINE2">  
<path>USM</path>    
</racine>

<racine name="RACINE3"> 
<path>src</path>    
</racine>

<racine name="RACINE4"> 
<path></path>   
</racine>

<racine name="RACINE5"> 
<path></path>   
</racine>

<racine name="RACINE6"> 
<path></path>   
</racine>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe f_path = f_path + path + "/"?